# Wrapping Switchery in a Directive VueJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, switchery

I am trying to wrap the [Switchery iOS 7](https://github.com/abpetkov/switchery) in a Vue Directive but I had no success until now! Somebody to help me?

There is my code [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/gustavobissolli/amv3504f/).

**JS**

```
Vue.directive('plSwitchery', {
  twoWay: true,

  deep: true,

  params: [],

  bind: function() {

    var self = this,
      value = self.value,
      el = self.el;

    el.checked = true;

    new Switchery(el);

    $(el).on('change', function(a) {
      value = !value;
      self.set(value);
      alert(self.value);
    });

  },
  update: function(value) {
    window.console.log('directive update');
  },
  unbind: function() {
    this.el.destroy();
  }
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selected: 1,
  },
  methods: {
    onChange: function() {
      alert('Do HTTP request');
    }
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">

  <input type="checkbox" v-pl-switchery="selected" />

</div>
```

So I could wrap it and it's partially working... Now I need to know how to update my SELECTED data and how to call the method onChange when the user trigger the change event to call the server and update some information on the database!

I don't really get how to deal with it!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I gave up Switchery plugin and I've made my own component!

There is my solution!

**JS**

```
Vue.component('plSwitch', {
  template: '#ck',
  props: {
    model: {
      default () {
        return false
      }
    },
    text: {
      default () {
        return;
      }
    },
    disabled: {
      default () {
        return false
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onChange() {
      console.log('oi')
      vm.$dispatch('onChange')
    }
  }
})

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#add',
  data: {
    state: true
  },
  events: {
    onChange: function() {
      alert('Do HTTP request');
    }
  }
})
```

**CSS**

```
.label_switch {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: relative;
}
.label_switch input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.label_switch input[type="checkbox"] + span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 38px;
  height: 18px;
  position: relative;
}
.label_switch input[type="checkbox"] + span:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 38px;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
}
.label_switch:hover input[type="checkbox"] + span:before {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px #eee;
}
.label_switch input[type="checkbox"] + span:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: solid 1px #dfdfdf;
  box-shadow: 2px 1px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)
}
.label_switch input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span:after {
  left: 18px;
  border: solid 1px #5FBEAA;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.label_switch input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span:before,
.label_switch input[type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked + span:before {
  border: 1px solid #5FBEAA;
  background-color: #5FBEAA;
}
.label_switch:hover input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span:before {
  box-shadow: none;
}
.label_switch input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + span {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
.label_switch input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + span:before {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
.label_switch input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + span:after {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
.label_switch input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + span:after {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.label_switch input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + span:before,
.label_switch input[type="checkbox"]:disabled + span:after {
  cursor: no-drop;
}
.label_switch input[type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked + span:before {} .m-r-5 {
  margin-right: 5px !important;
}
.m-l-5 {
  margin-left: 5px !important;
}
.disabled {
  cursor: no-drop!important;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<template id="ck">
  <label class="label_switch" :class="{ 'disabled' : disabled }">
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="model" :false-value="false" :true-value="true" :disabled="disabled" @click="onChange()">
    <span :class="{ 'm-r-5': text != '' }"></span> {{ text }}
  </label>
</template>

<div id="add">
  <pre>{{ $data | json }}</pre>
  <pl-switch :model.sync="state" text="Example"></pl-switch>
</div>
```

Let me know you do you guys think!

Answer (score 1):

The quick way would be to do: `this.vm.onChange()`, but that makes it nessessary for the parent component to have a method by that name, and restricts the reusability of that directive.

Another way would be to simply create a watch in the component and maybe move the `onChange` funciton from `methods:` to `watch:`:

```
watch: {
  'selected': function() {
    alert('Do HTTP request');
  }
}
```

Third option would be to $emit an event in the component from the directive:

```
// in the directive
this.vm.$emit('swicth-changed',value)

//if you have different switches you can name them with the directive argument:

// v-pl-switchery:name="selected" 

this.vm.$emit('switch-changed',this.arg,value) // this.arg gives you the 'name'

<input type="checkbox" v-pl-switchery="selected" @switch-changed="onChange"/>
```

For your situation I would go with the simple second approach

Comment: note: edited the second example, had the watch name wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the help Linus! Actually I gave up from Switchery plugin and I've my own component! I am gonna post an answer... please could you see if it's cool? Thanks man!